# How by Gradle create external folder config with config files inside it?

Tags: java, gradle, kotlin

I use the Gradle [shadow](https://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/) plugin to create one executable jar.

Nice.

But I have some external config files. They must be external. As a result the user can edit them.

So I need a structure like this:

```
\myapp
 - myapp_executable.jar
   \config\db.config
   \config\log4j.xml
```

So what kind of gradle tasks I have to use to get this structure?